# how do i deploy to other severs with juju

Tags: juju

My question is how do i deploy services via juju-gui to other servers without using MAAS? In a previous posting I tried this and failed no matter how much or little I changed the procedure.

Now I have seen some documentation on the null option and commands that say deploy to another another machine. The question is I have server A-D, how do i manage resources from A and deploy applications and charms to B, C, and D ?

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there is no support for the placement directives (--to) in the juju gui at this stage.

You need to install a juju gui for each environment that you are wanting to deploy services to. So if you are managing two environments, one on MAAS, and another on OpenStack say, you'd need to install the juju-gui on both.